# Cocos2D label not visible, black screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5

I have implemented the CCLabelProtocol and CCRGBAProtocol with a class which I named Label:

```
#import <cocos2d.h>

@interface Label : CCNode <CCLabelProtocol, CCRGBAProtocol>

@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSString* string;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) ccColor3B color;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) GLubyte opacity;

- (id) initWithString: (NSString*) aString;

@end
```

Since it comes handy I also made a initWithString method:

```
#import "Label.h"

@implementation Label

@synthesize string,opacity,color;

- (id) initWithString: (NSString*) aString
{
    if(self=[super init])
    {
        string= aString;
        color.r=255;
        color.g=0;
        color.b=0;
        opacity= 10;
    }
    return self;
}

- (ccColor3B) color
{
    return color;
}

@end
```

Then in the HelloWorldLayer's init method I do this:

```
    Label* label= [[Label alloc]initWithString: @"Start"];
    CCMenuItemLabel* item= [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel: label block:^(id sender)
    {
        NSLog(@"Label Clicked");
    }];
    CCMenu* menu= [CCMenu menuWithItems: item, nil];
    [self addChild: menu];
```

I am using the a plain cocos2d template, so this is inside a CCLayer class.
The screen is black, I don't get the label to appear as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you merely adopted some protocols, but subclassed from CCNode. CCNode is a non-rendering (invisible) node.

If you want a label, subclass from CCLabelTTF and omit the protocols since CCLabelTTF already implements them.

However it's overkill to create a CCLabelTTF subclass unless you want to change how the label behaves or renders. If all you need to change is text and color, use the [CCLabelTTF initializers](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest_2.x/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_label_t_t_f.html) and its color property.

```
Label* label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Start" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:24];
label.color = ccRED;
CCMenuItemLabel* item = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel: label block:^(id sender)
{
    NSLog(@"Label Clicked");
}];
CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item, nil];
[self addChild:menu];
```